# VIrtualBox doesn't offer USB 2.0 Controller, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I just (re)installed VirtualBox after doing a "reset" on my Windows 10 laptop.

I found that in the Settings dialog box, I can no longer offer USB 2.0 for my guest machines; the options only list USB 1.1 and none other (see picture)

[image: Settings dialog box, USB page, showing only USB 1.1 option exists]

Any idea what went wrong?

I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.22 r144080, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently I have to install "VirtualBox Extension Pack" first before the USB 2.0 (and 3.0) options appear.